# Integer division in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, casting, clisp

When I do `(/ 7 2)`, what should I do to get the result `3`?  If I do (/ 7 2.0), I get `3.5`, which is as expected.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
(floor 7 2)
```

Ref: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Basic_integer_arithmetic#Common_Lisp

Answer (score 21):

See [FLOOR, CEILING and TRUNCATE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_floorc.htm) in ANSI Common Lisp.

Examples (see the positive and negative numbers):

```
CL-USER 218 > (floor -5 2)
-3
1

CL-USER 219 > (ceiling -5 2)
-2
-1

CL-USER 220 > (truncate -5 2)
-2
-1

CL-USER 221 > (floor 5 2)
2
1

CL-USER 222 > (ceiling 5 2)
3
-1

CL-USER 223 > (truncate 5 2)
2
1
```

Usually for division to integer TRUNCATE is used.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `floor` function:

```
(floor 7 2)
3
1
```

Note that it returns multiple values, and you only need the first one. Since `floor` returns multiple values, that can be done with `multiple-value-bind` as follows:

```
(multiple-value-bind (q r) (floor 7 2) q)
=> 3
```

**Edit:** As Rainer notes in his comment, you can just pass the result of `floor` as an argument if all you need is the quotient.

```
[1]> (floor 7 2)
3 ;
1
[2]> (+ (floor 7 2) 5)
8
[3]>
```

I'm leaving the reference to `multiple-value-bind` in the answer, since it's an important function to be familiar with.

Comment: how do i get the first value? does it return a list??

Comment: that's not needed. the first value is automatically passed to the next code. You need the MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND if you want all values or some. (values (floor 7 2)) just returns the first.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `floor` function. In SBCL:

```
* (floor (/ 7 2))

3
1/2
```

Two values are returned, the integer part and the fractional part.

Comment: FLOOR does the division by itself.